# Show Multiple images using foreach loop using Glide

Tags: java, android

I have developed a shopping application, the final order placing order i have to show all the cart product details from realm database. here i can fetch all the details and working perfect except the product images. here i am using enhanced for loop. i am getting exact image URL, but image view not repeating like text view, Please help me, your help will be appreciated.

```
 void productname(){
        pname = "";
        pimage= "";

        for (Cart cart : cartItems) {
            pname = pname + cart.getName() + "!";
            pname = pname.replaceAll("!", "\n\n");
            pimage=pimage+Constants.getProductBaseUrlThumb(getContext()) + cart.getImage();
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(pimage)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(ivProductImage);

        }
```

Comment: Where is `TextView`?

Comment: tvProductNames.setText(pname);

Comment: its working fine and repeating , but image view showing last product only

Comment: @IrshadMadappat for use multiple imageview use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Is `tvProductNames.setText(pname);` in for loop? As i can see, it is not. Also you use same `ImageView` everytime in loop. Consider using `RecyclerView`

Comment: understood my problem , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your code is That you have provided Single ImageView which can hold maximum 1 Image in it.

**Why your ImageView shows last Image Only ?**

**Answer :** According to your code You setting the image to ImageView. It working properly But Problem with it. That when the foreach loop ends your imageview get last url of Image from ArrayList.

So Better Use `RecyclerView` to show multiple image in list.

For The Reference and Docs you can [Click Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example).

Answer (score 3):

of course it will not work as expected, for that, please use `recycler view` or dynamically generate `ImageView`s. It is impossible to show multiple images in one ImageView through glide

Comment: here i am not following recyclerview, so i cant do that

Comment: @IrshadMadappat then you have to provide multiple imageview which will hold image according to text.

Comment: I can Provide you example of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from my util library 
https://github.com/Link184/Extensions/blob/master/extensions/src/main/java/com/link184/extensions/AndroidExtensions.kt

```
/**
 * [ImageView] and url will be grouped consecutively. Take care to pass all urls and ImageViews
 * in the same order.
 * @throws IllegalStateException when image view array size is different from url array size
 */
fun Array<ImageView>.loadUri(vararg uri: Uri, block: GlideRequest<Drawable>.() -> GlideRequest<Drawable> = { this }) {
    if (size != uri.size) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Image view and image url count do not correspond.")
    }
    forEachIndexed { index, it ->
        it.loadUri(uri[index], block)
    }
}

inline fun ImageView.loadUri(uri: Uri, block: GlideRequest<Drawable>.() -> GlideRequest<Drawable> = { this }) {
    block(GlideApp.with(this).load(uri)).into(this)
}
```

Just call

```
itemViewsArray.loadUri(cartItems.map { it.toUriFunction() })
```